# Is there anything missing in the pipeline on Azure?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

I am trying to deploy angular web app using Microsoft Azure Dev cloud services. I found that the pipeline process looks successful, but somehow after completion it shows 2 steps out of 10 in grey colour (which is very kind of confusing). As, I am very new to the Azure, I am not sure what am I doing wrong here. I have attached the herewith screenshots of the steps ?

[image: Logs of <code>Step:1</code>]

[image: <code>Status of all pipeline steps</code>]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, nothing is wrong, its just those tasks are built-in. they are not part of your job, rather platform setup.

Comment: One more thing I have noticed that, when I open the angular webapp page, it route back to the default web page generated during the creation of app resources during set up in azure poral. It does not route to the Angular App web page which we build up on the Azure DevOps. Could you please help me how to resolve it?

Comment: you should create a new question for this one, as this is a completely different question. also, consider accepting this answer if it helped you :)